# In context of defining a hamiltonian of a system, can someone please explain the meaning of zero-point oscillations/vibrations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

I came across this term while studying electron delocalization in amorphous semiconductors. The delocalization of the electronics wavefunction is explained in terms of zero-point oscillations.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy) might help.